# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `createCourse` is marked as required in `CoursesPage`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My code works without `mapDispatchToProps` function and setting the `dispatch` function at the handleSubmit and at `CoursesPage.propTypes` instead of using `createCourse`. I've updated the `CoursesPage.js` code in order to use `mapDispatchToProps` and something has broke. [This is my code at sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-smoke-vd05b?file=/src/components/courses/CoursesPage.js:1762-1780)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You need to pass `mapDispatchToProps` to `connect`

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CoursesPage);
```

2. `createCourse` is not a prop, it's a function you're importing